# copy data from bucket to the home directory of `cloud shell terminal

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am working with `goole cloud (GCP)` and have some files on the bucket. I am trying to copy data from the bucket to the home directory of `cloud shell terminal`. I can not find a command for that. do you know the command?

I tried the following command which is not working:

```
gsutil cp gs://my-bucket client-name@cloudshell:~
```

Answer (score 1):

While you are at the HOME dir in your Cloud Shell run this:

```
gsutil cp -r gs://my-bucket/* ./
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simply the `~`

```
# For one file
gsutil cp gs://my-bucket/my-file ~/

# For a directory
gsutil cp -r gs://my-bucket/* ~/
```